# How to authenticate Azure Directory using API even when MFA is on

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, token

I want to authenticate a valid Azure Directory user from my application. So the output that I want is the user is valid or not?

I use this API `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token` with following urlencoded body like `client_id`, `scope`, `client_secret`, `username`, `password`, `grant_type` the for the authentication but this API is working only when the user disabled their MFA, but I want to authenticate even the user has enabled MFA.

Answer (score 0):

You have hit one of the limitations of the ROPC flow.
It is not possible to authenticate a user with MFA enabled with that flow.
The solution will be to change your application to use an interactive flow like Authorization Code flow.
This will require that your app forwards the user to Azure AD to sign in, and then your application gets access tokens in exchange.

Pros:

- You don't need to handle passwords
- All the security features of Azure AD can be used, including MFA

Cons:

- Complexity will increase (libraries help here)

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

If you have a Javascript front-end app, you can use MSAL.js to handle the authentication.
Other OpenID Connect compatible libraries can also be used.